# Is it helpful to create thread in service to do heavy work?

Tags: android, android-service

Should I create thread to do heavy work in service, if not will it has any risk, lead to ANR or Force Close?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a thread for that. Or you can use a subclass of AsyncTask and do it in doInBackground().

You can find documentation about AsyncTask [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it Service is same as activity all run in main thread

Answer (score 0):

In android create thread with with following

- thread
- worker thread
- handler thread
- Asynctask